# Interpreting a regression following PCA

Tags: regression, pca, interpretation

I am looking for some help and I am struggling to find any answers.
For my course i have completed Principal Component Analysis on my data (a health survey with 8 different variables - smoking, drinking, obesity, fruit and veg intake, activity levels, mental health, self-assessed health and cardiovascular condition).
I decided to retain four components as this allowed me to retain 91% of the variance.
I am now planning to run some regressions with a variable long-term illness as my outcome variable and the components as my explanatories. I am just really confused on how I actually interpret my data when it comes to using components and was hoping that somebody could point me in the right direction. In an ordinary regression i could use a variable like smoking and drinking to see the effect it has on long term illness and could interpret that easily but this is beyond me.

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 3):

One approach is you don't attempt to interpret individual variables once PCA is applied. The idea being you found your latent factors, and these are now your variables.

Another approach is that the PC is nothing but a linear combination of your original variables. You know the coefficients of each variable, so you can easily imply the effective slope of each variable. It will be the sum product of the slopes of PCA regression and the coefficients of the variable in each of the components.